# apache and mysql ports

Tags: php, mysql, apache, vtiger

I am installing an open source software, which is `vtiger, and that use mysql and php

The first screen in installing that software asks for mysql and apache code,

the installation tools set these values as:

apache port 8888

and mysql port 33307

but when I open my xampp I see different ports like this:

[image]

Should I change the values of these ports to the values that I see in the image or not?

Thanks in advance

#### edit

this is what the installation tool suggest
[image]

so should I replace the 8888 with the 8082 
and should I replace the 33307 with 3306 ?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql's default port is 3306, and your XAMPP control panel shows that's the one in use, so you don't need to touch anything here.

As per apache webserver, the default http port is 80, which in this case you could access with

```
http://localhost
```

but you can use pretty much whatever you want as long as you append the port number to the url

```
http://localhost:8082

http://localhost:8082/anotherpage.html
```

Your Apache webserver is listening to both 4430 and 8082. I wonder if `http://localhost:4430` would try to open as https, but I believe that is irrelevant at this point.

Long story short: if you aren't planning to use any other app on port 80, just set Apache to listen to port 80 to forget about appending port numbers on your urls.

Comment: my question is should I change the values in the installation tool to the values that I showed you in the image?  I know that I don't want ot change the values or mysql port and apache but the installation tool set them a different values than the values in the image. best regards .

Comment: I am using port 80 for another thing, but please this is not my question my friend

Comment: Just leave it as it is. If the installation script said otherwise, perhaps it's outdated or has a typo.

Comment: please check my edited question, i tried to make the question more clear

Comment: I get it. But if the installer didn't edit the configuration files properly that's not your problem. XAMPP is informing what the real ports are. Use those.

Comment: so you suggest replacing the values in the installer or not?